# Android apk could load native library

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

> E/AndroidRuntime(724): Caused by:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load libann from loader

dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.android.mymapsforge-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.android.mymapsforge-1]: findLibrary returned null.
```

I write a android application in which I want to use the native-library, my console in ecliose have show that the libann.so is successfully build.

But test the android application on emulator, the logcat tell me the above error.

I checked that "libann.so" exists in folders "MyMapsforge\libs\armeabi" and "MyMapsforge\libs\armeabi-v7a".

My mainactivity function has a method:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("libann");
}
```

I want to know if its because any setting of loading native library path is missing, or any other error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your library's name is **libann.so**, you need to call System.loadLibrary("**ann**");